# Installing stone veneer on the front of a log home

Tags: siding

We are planning to install stone veneer panels on the front of our log home. We will be doing a full wall in the front which is under our covered porch. The question we have is how to deal with the log corners. We have 3 corners that stick out like an “I” because the middle of our house is not log. Should we cover them the best we can with some type of window wrap or trim pieces that match the veneer panels or can we just cut them off flush with the logs?

Comment: Pictures would help.  The stone panel maker might have trim/corner pieces to match the panels.  My morterless brick maker had all the trim pieces needed to match(at extra cost).

Comment: Does the manufacturer have clips that allow for expansion/contraction of the wood you're attaching to? If not, tread carefully.

Comment: Can you elaborate on: _'3 corners that stick out like an “I” because the middle of our house is not log_?

Comment: I will try to get some pictures uploaded in the next couple of days. We are really rethinking this project because of the expanding and contracting of the logs. Thank you for pointing that out!! Over the past 25 years of living in this house it definitely shifts due to cold or warm weather and we live in northern Wisconsin where the weather changes by the day and the winters can be long and cold.